# How to know if Firestore had propagated the newly updated security rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Firestore can take up to 10 mins to propagate newly updated security rules, says Firestore. So instead of patiently waiting for 10 mins for every updated security rules, how else can we tell that the security rules has been propagated successfully. So one does not need to wait for 10 mins and 1 second later to test the behaviour?

[image]

Comment: Yea I think 10 minutes is a long time... would be useful if something can pop up in the console. I think although it updates very fast, but not as quick as the Realtime Database with the useful simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There unfortunately is no built in notification that the new rules have been deployed. You will have to test something about the change you made to the rules to see if they've been deployed.

For example: if you added a new validation that disallows writing a certain field, try writing *with* that field. Once that write fails, you know that the new rules are deployed.

As J. Doe commented, usually it takes much less than the advertised 10 minutes before the rules are deployed. In practice, I frequently see that my updated rules are deployed by the time I've modified the code to deal with the change.

Comment: Is there a debug console / log for firestore security rules? So we can console.log('version #').

Comment: Nope, there's no such thing. The "best" I've come up with is to include a version check on an otherwise unused collection in my rules, and update that check with every change. But I never got around to implementing it, as it turns out the deploy delay doesn't get into my way all that often (though it's incredibly annoying when it does).

Answer (score -1):

You can check the Firebase Console (on the firebase.google.com website). Your rules display there under the `Rules` tab.

[image]